# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.) when connecting BigQuery to PostgresQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

New to beam and GCP/dataflow. I'm working on a dataflow flex template in Python to write a table from BigQuery to a PostgreSQL database and I'm running into this error:
`Error message from worker: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)`

I've created a VPC subnetwork with an external IP and whitelisted it on the PostgreSQL server. Is this error because I've configured the the VPC incorrectly or is something wrong with my template code? Or an error with my firewall settings or something like that?

Full stack trace:

```
Error message from worker: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2514)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$1.process(JdbcIO.java:1778)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:213)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:158)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.awaitCompletion(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:123)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:550)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:653)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteFn.getConnection(JdbcIO.java:2517)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteFn.executeBatch(JdbcIO.java:2569)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteFn.processElement(JdbcIO.java:2527)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
    org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
    org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:374)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:106)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:649)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteFn.getConnection(JdbcIO.java:2517)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteFn.executeBatch(JdbcIO.java:2569)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteFn.processElement(JdbcIO.java:2527)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2514)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$1.process(JdbcIO.java:1778)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:213)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:158)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.awaitCompletion(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:123)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:550)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:551)
    java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)
    java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
    org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    ... 37 more
```